# Running C++ with input in the command line

Tags: c++, shell, command

I need to have my program work by typing the code below in the linux shell

```
./[program name] < [input file name]
e.g. ./program1 < input.txt
```

program includes, for example

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    string file;
    cin >> file;
    fstream input_file (file, fstream::in);
}
```

it works when I type

```
./program1
input.txt
```

but not when

```
./program1 < input.txt
```

Any help?

Comment: What are the contents of `input.txt`

Comment: `./program1 < input.txt` is using the contents of `input.txt` to get the file name to open.

Comment: @KORguy your input.txt contains the name of the file you wanna open??

Comment: It just contains a bunch of numbers I need to process

Comment: Is the first number in that file the name of the file you want to open? That is what your code is attempting. You probably want to change your program to use command line arguments instead of prompting for a file name or only prompt if no argument was passed. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/)

Comment: @drescherjm I kind of tried it by checking elements in argv, but it doesn't seem to recognize "< input.txt" part. it only contained "./program1"

Comment: @brc-dd no input.txt is just an input file that contains data I wanna process.

Comment: That is not a command line argument. Get rid of the `<` so after your program is modified to handle command line arguments use `./program1 input.txt` either that or modify the program to just read the data from `cin` meaning don't ask for a file name. The `./program1 < input.txt` would support reading from `cin`

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks a lot. I will try either methods :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open the file using `fstream` if you just want it's data.

Call the code using `./program < input.txt`.

Code:

```cpp
int main() {
    // no need to open file here start reading data directly from input.txt
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n; // should print the first number present in your input.txt file.
    return 0;
}
```